# Toggling div display state on click of links

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get each div to display when it respective link is clicked, but I keep getting error

> Cannot read property 'style' of null

While my one bit works, I am not sure if I am choosing right syntax `event.target.style.display = 'none'`.

How can I cycle through the clicks and make every div appear and others disappear if one is opened?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wmrorvrx/)

```
const tab = document.querySelector('body');
const tab1 = document.querySelector('#home')
tab.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
    tab1.style.display == 'none'
})
```

Comment: `tab1.style.display == 'none'` need to be `tab1.style.display = 'none'`

Comment: That and your fiddle isn't throwing any errors

Comment: in you fiddle, you have same id's for links and divs, which is not right

Comment: shouldn't it be the same so it loads that div when click? @techLove

Comment: @nofel take  help from here:- https://codepen.io/eadsimone/pen/rLVzEW

Comment: @Nofel no, you can do like this <a href="#home">Home</a>. ids can never be same

Comment: @AlivetoDie It doesn't work.

Comment: @Nofel  i said take help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

1. Fix your ids - they should be unique so remove them from your links
2. Add a class to your links
3. Add a class to your content divs
4. Use your links properly - make them target the corresponding div
5. Wrap your content divs in a wrapper div so you can use the css I have added (see code)
6. Update js (comments in code bleow)

```js
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('link'),         // add a class to the links and get them all
  contentDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('content');  // same with the content blocks

for (i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {                        // loop through the links to add the event listeners
  var link = links[i];

  // add event listener
  link.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    // reset color and hide content:
    for (a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
      // number of links should match number of content
      links[a].style.backgroundColor = 'magenta';
      contentDivs[a].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // set colour of clicked
    event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';

    // show clicked content
    document.getElementById(event.target.getAttribute("href").substring(1)).style.display = 'block';
  })
}
```

```css
ul {
  wudth: 100%;
  clear: both
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
}

li a {
  background: magenta;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* add this so only home is showing when page loads */
.content:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#home" class="link">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact" class="link">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#articles" class="link">Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#connect" class="link">Connect</a></li>
</ul>

<div>
  <div id="home" class="content">
    home
    <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque erat velit, placerat sit amet nisl sed, aliquet bibendum nunc. Donec varius dui sed velit volutpat, et rutrum turpis fini
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="contact" class="content">
    contact
    <br> . Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit amet
    hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
  </div>
  <div id="articles" class="content">
    articles
    <br> . Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit amet
    hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
  </div>
  <div id="connect" class="content">
    connect
    <br> . Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit amet
    hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does `getAttribute("href").substring(1))` do?

Comment: Hi Nofel, sorry I went home last night.  You need to loop through otherwise you won't bind the event to each link.  The `getAttribute("href").substring(1))` gets the links href and then removes the first character (ie removes the hash)

Comment: Hahaha,  I'm still learning when it comes to js - there are loads of stuff that I could do better but I get by! I use this forum to see how others would do the same thing and it is very interesting and you learn a lot

Comment: When i inset it in my code it gives me error is console. ` Cannot read property 'appendChild' of undefined`

Comment: Could you ask a new question please as the code I used doesn't have appendChild in it

Comment: appendChild was in a chrome extension, sorry about it. One big question, why we using an index loop inside event listener? I know the Index `i` get all list but what about a?

Answer (score 0):

So, my approach to this would be to bind an event to all of your links, and then hide away all of the content sections, then showing the one you want to display (they could also be hidden by default in the css). A common class for all the content sections will help you probably. I used a data-attribute to pair to the clickable link because ID's need to be unique per page.

I played around with it a bit to demonstrate, but there is still more for you to do, managing the color of the anchors and all that.

```js
const tab = document.querySelector('body');
//get all clickables
const home = document.querySelector('#home');
const contact = document.querySelector('#contact');
const articles = document.querySelector('#articles');
const connect = document.querySelector('#connect');
// loop through all clickables and bind events
[home, contact, articles, connect].forEach(function(tab){
   tab.addEventListener('click', function(event){
      var selection = event.currentTarget.id;
        //get our content sections
        var collapse = document.querySelectorAll('.collapsible');
        for(var i = 0; i < collapse.length; i++){
                //loop through them all and hide
          collapse[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        
     event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'grey';
            //show the one we want
      document.querySelector(".collapsible[data-pair='"+selection+"']").style.display = 'block';
   })
});
```

```css
ul{
  wudth:100%;
  clear:both
}
li{
  padding:10px;
  color:white;
  list-style:none;
}
li a{
  background:magenta;
  color:white;
  padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="articles">Articles</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="connect">Connect</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="home_content" class='collapsible' data-pair="home">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque erat velit, placerat sit amet nisl sed, aliquet bibendum nunc. Donec varius dui sed velit volutpat, et rutrum turpis fini
</div>
<br>
<div id="contact_content" class='collapsible' data-pair="contact">
. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit amet hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
</div>
<div id="articles_content" class='collapsible' data-pair="articles">
. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit amet hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
</div>
<div id="connect_content" class='collapsible' data-pair="connect">
. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Vestibulum aliquam iaculis turpis et efficitur. Integer sollicitudin tincidunt imperdiet. Nam pharetra orci ac viverra dapibus. Ut feugiat nisi sit amet hendrerit scelerisque. Nulla scelerisque mauris metus, eu facilisis lectus euismod vel. Pellentesque magna mi, scelerisque vel rutrum quis, volutpat et diam.
</div>
```

hope that is helpful to getting you started.

P.S. As noted in the comments, you also don't want the double equals on assignment.

Comment: Thanks, I am getting hold of javascript. I see you looped on the list of items in the array, Can I make it dynamic, which just that event.target and use that as it might have more or less. So don't want to hardcode.